# Reflection not return value

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I am trying to access field value using reflection, but cant make it work

```
public class Menssagens
{
    public string Teste2;

    public void Falar(string key, string id)
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText(@"bin/" + id + ".json");
        Menssagens dotNet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Menssagens>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(dotNet.Teste2); //Works fine
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(Menssagens).GetField(key).GetValue(this)); 
        //Dont works, returns nothing
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're accessing the property value on `this`.  You never set it on `this`, so it returns null.
You probably want to access the value on the instance you created.

In fact, your method should be `static`.